# how to display text properly inside equation in latex

Tags: math-mode, pdftex

how to display text properly inside equation in latex

```
 \def\DevnagVersion{2.15}  
 \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}  
 \usepackage[lined,ruled,vlined,resetcount]{algorithm2e}  
 \renewcommand{\thealgocf}{}  
 \usepackage{csquotes}  
 \usepackage{wfrac}  
 \usepackage{array}  
 \usepackage{caption}  
 \providecommand{\SetAlgoLined}{\SetLine}  
 \hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}  
 \usepackage{filecontents}  
 \usepackage{cite}  
 \usepackage{devanagari}  
 \begin{document}
 \begin{equation}  
    PMI({\dn u(pAd} + {\dn \7{K}f}) \\  
    = Round(LOG((F({\dn u(pAd} + {\dn \7{K}f})/TotalBigrams)/( (F({\dn u(pAd})/TotalUnigrams)*(F({\dn \7{K}f})/TotalUnigrams)))\\  
    = Round(LOG( (1/1298) / (20/1299)*(6/1299))),2)\\  
    = Round(Log(0.000770416/(0.0153964588*0.0046189376)),2)\\  
    = Round(Log(10.8333397535),2)\\  
    = Round(1.0347623636,2)\\  
    = 1.03\\  
    \end{equation}
\end{document
```

The output it displays is

```
 PMI(u Ú +)
 = Round(LOG((F (u Ú + )/TotalBigrams)/((F(u Ú)/TotalUnigrams)*(F()/TotalUnigrams)))
 = Round(LOG((1/1298)/(20/1299) ∗ (6/1299))), 2)
 = Round(Log(0.000770416/(0.0153964588∗0.0046189376)), 2)
 = Round(Log(10.8333397535), 2)
 = Round(1.0347623636, 2)
 = 1.03
```

Comment: Properly isn't definitely the way you posted ;-)

Comment: What are `\dn` and `\7` supposed to do?

Comment: The text is written in Hindi language, i am using     \def\DevnagVersion{2.15}      \usepackage{devanagari}

Comment: The text is displaying in Hindi by using \dn{} and every character is written there.........anyways that is not the problem..... I am posting the output also, which is not proper.

Comment: You cannot have multiline `equation`s, an alternative would `align`. You are using `mathtools`, right? If so, use `\text{word}`, though all this looks more like an algorithm or even program listing.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Anyway, you probably `\text` (or, more appropriate for this scenario, `\DeclareMathOperator`).

Comment: No i am not using mathtools, i want to display the output in multiple lines, as it is displaying in the asked question.....should i use \begin{eqnarray}? mathtools need package installation, right?

Comment: @userjha -- `mathtools` is part of the standard tex live distribution, so you should have it already.  i'd suggest using `multline` instead of `equation`, and after the first `\\ ` wrap `aligned` around the rest of the lines and add `&` before the initial `=` sign in each line.  these environments are provided by `amsmath` (loaded by `mathtools`), and you can see the documentation with `texdoc amsmath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hide the Devanagari bits in `\text`:

```
\def\DevnagVersion{2.15}  
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\usepackage[lined,ruled,vlined,resetcount]{algorithm2e}
\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{wfrac}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\providecommand{\SetAlgoLined}{\SetLine}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{devanagari}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Round}{Round}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Log}{Log}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\mathrm{PMI}(\text{\dn u(pAd} + \text{\dn \7{K}f}) \\
  &= \Round\mleft(\Log
       \frac{\dfrac{F(\text{\dn u(pAd} + \text{\dn \7{K}f}))}{\mathrm{TotalBigrams}}}
            {\dfrac{F(\text{\dn u(pAd}))}{\mathrm{TotalUnigrams}}*
             \dfrac{F(\text{\dn \7{K}f})}{\mathrm{TotalUnigrams}}}
     \mright)\\
  &= \Round\mleft(\Log
       \frac{\dfrac{1}{\mathstrut 1298}}
            {\dfrac{\mathstrut 20}{1299}*\dfrac{6}{1299}}
     ,2\mright)\\  
  &= \Round\mleft(\Log\frac{0.000770416}{0.0153964588*0.0046189376},2\mright)\\
  &= \Round(\Log(10.8333397535),2)\\
  &= \Round(1.0347623636,2)\\
  &= 1.03
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I saved this as `jha.dn` and ran

```
rm -f jha.tex && devnag jha.dn > jha.tex && pdflatex jha
```

getting the following result, which fits in a column

[image]

Note: I commented out the `wfrac` package, that I don't have on my system.

Comment: @ egreg Excellent............the answer that I never thought, never expected that i can get......I was not knowing I can get this as perfect as u posted.........thanks a lot

Comment: @ egreg  Are you working with Hindi data for any of your project?

Comment: @userjha I happened to learn about `devnag` for a couple of answers; I know absolutely nothing about Hindi, but I know a little about TeX. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is almost impossible to figured out ... so I guess that you like to have something like this:

[image]

Above picture I obtain by:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}%preview enable showing math
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath too

\begin{document}
    \begin{flalign*}
PMI(A + B) 
    & = \mathrm{Round}\bigl(\log(F(A + Bf)\mathrm{/TotalBigrams/}
            (F(A)\mathrm{/TotalUnigrams/}*F(Bf)\mathrm{/TotalUnigrams/})\bigr)\\
    & = \mathrm{Round}\bigl(\log(1/1298 /(20/1299)*(6/1299)),2\bigr)\\
    & = \mathrm{Round}\bigl(\log(0.000770416/(0.0153964588*0.0046189376)),2\bigr)\\
    & = \mathrm{Round}\bigl(\log(10.8333397535),2\bigr)\\
    & = \mathrm{Round}\bigl(1.0347623636,2\bigr)\\
    & = 1.03
   \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

In equations I omit all characters/symbols which are defined with your language. To insert them back, you will need enclosed into `\text{...}` as other suggest in their comments. I also didn't bother what you mind with symbol `\`, so I left it as was used.

Comment: @userjha, you are welcome. It seems that egreg has better "crystal ball" for guessing, what you actually looking for :-). Happy TeXing!

Comment: :-) Happy TeXing!